# Mongoose: Update/Insert in nested subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've seen quite a few examples here in stackoverflow, but none of them have been useful to me. Maybe my scheme is wrong?

I need to insert new records into a nested document using Mongoose (I would like to add within the `"history"` array). If the document already exists, I must only update it, if it does not exist, a new document must be added. I have the following scheme:

```
let equipment_json = {
    controls: [{
        _id: con.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        history: [{
            _id: con.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            new: Boolean,
        }]
    }]
};

let equipment_schema = new con.Schema(equipment_json);
let Equipment = con.mongoose.model('Equipment', Equipment_schema);
```

This code should perform the update:

```
Equipment.update({
  '_id': object_equipment.id_equipment,
  'controls._id': object_equipment.id_control_type
},{
  $set: {
    'controls.$.history.$': {
      new: true
    }
  }
},
{
  upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true
},
function (err, doc ) {
  console.log( doc );
})
```

Before using `update()` I used `find()` to check what it finds according to the criteria. Using `find()`, it returns the document, however, when I want to use `update()` it does not add to the array "`controls"`, the `"new": "true"`. I tried as much with `$set` as with `$push`.

Comment: You didn't say which element of history array to match. Is there only one, multiple, is it even known on the call site?

Comment: I need to add the value of "new" to the "history" array, as long as "_id" and "controls._id match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only necessary to modify the following code:

```
'controls.$.history.$': {
   new: true
 }
```

by

```
'controls.$.history': {
      new: true
 }
```